# sum 2 graphs in neo4j with multiple MERGE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**in brief:** how can we `MERGE` multiple nodes and relations just like the way we do with `MATCH` and `CREATE`: we can do multiple `CREATE` or `MATCH` for nodes or relations, separated with comma, but this action is not allowed with `MERGE`

**in detail:** suppose I have two graphs:

```
G1: (a)-[r1]->(b)<-[r2]-(c)
G2: (a)-[r1]->(b)<-[r3]-(d)
```

I have `G1` inserted in neo4j, and `G2` ready to push to db. The normal way to do it is to merge each node pair and then merge the relation; in this example for `r1` relation there would be no change in db, since `G1` already has the relation, however for the second one, my CQL first create node `d` then add relation `r3`

Is there a way to push `G2` to db in one step? something like:

```
MERGE (a), (b), (c), (a)-[r1]->(b)<-[r3]-(d)
```

to create such result:

```
(a)-[r1]->(b)<-[r2]-(c)
           ^
           |
          [r3]
           |
          (d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with a single MERGE statement. You would need to follow the pattern of doing a MERGE for each node, then a MERGE for each relationship.

That said, Neo4j does use transactions, so while this is broken into multiple clauses in your Cypher query, the transaction is applied atomically when committed.